# How do I skip the tutorial?

Tags: xcom-2

No matter the difficulty, except on Legendary, I have no option but to replay the tutorial. I'd like to skip through all of this as I've already done the tutorial more than twice, and I see no option to skip to Iron Man mode without doing the tutorial.

Is there a way to completely skip the tutorial as I don't want to do another tutorial again if I start a new game.

Comment: Ah mandatory tutorials, the greatest enemy of the  gamer. ;-)

Comment: Sounds like something to be fixed in a later patch after the hell the gamers will give them. Usual stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can disable the tutorial by unchecking the tutorial box on the start game screen. It's in the box of settings below the difficulty selection.